# Azure ML studio export data Azure Storage V2

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-blob-storage

I already post my problem [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aff7df3f-afbc-4abc-8fb0-5597184fa6c1/export-data-blob-storage-v2?forum=MachineLearning) and they suggested me to post it here.
I am trying to export data from Azure ML to Azure Storage but I have this error:

Error writing to cloud storage: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.. Please check the url. . ( Error 0151 )

My blob storage configuration is Storage v2 / Standard and  Require secure transfer set as enabled.

If I set the Require secure transfer set as disabled, the export works fine.

**How can I export data to my blob storage with the require secure transfer set as enabled ?**

Comment: So there a few things to discuss, how are you trying to export the data ? is it programmatically ? or using a specific tool ?
Also, When enabling the require secure transfer, are you using HTTPS from the export process ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the offical tutorial [`Export to Azure Blob Storage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/export-to-azure-blob-storage), there are two authentication types for exporting data to Azure Blob Storage: SAS and Account. The description for them as below.

> 4. For **Authentication type**, choose **Public (SAS URL)** if you know that the storage supports access via a SAS URL.
>
>    A SAS URL is a special type of URL that can be generated by using an Azure storage utility, and is available for only a limited time. It contains all the information that is needed for authentication and download.
>
>    For **URI**, type or paste the full URI that defines the account and the public blob.
> 5. For private accounts, choose **Account**, and provide the account name and the account key, so that the experiment can write to the storage account.
>
>    - **Account name**: Type or paste the name of the account where you want to save the data. For example, if the full URL of the storage account is http://myshared.blob.core.windows.net, you would type myshared.
>    - **Account key**: Paste the storage access key that is associated with the account.

I try to use a simple module combination as the figure and Python code below to test the issue you got.

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):
    dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
    return dataframe1,
```

When I tried to use the authentication type `Account` of my Blob Storage V2 account, I got the same issue as yours which the error code is [Error 0151](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/errors/error-0151) as below via click the `View error log` Button under the link of `View output log`.

[image]

> **Error 0151**
>
> There was an error writing to cloud storage. Please check the URL.
>
> This error in Azure Machine Learning occurs when the module tries to write data to cloud storage but the URL is unavailable or invalid.
>
> **Resolution**
>   Check the URL and verify that it is writable.
>
> **Exception Messages**
>
> - Error writing to cloud storage (possibly a bad url).
> - Error writing to cloud storage: {0}. Please check the url.

Based on the error description above, the error should be caused by the blob url with SAS incorrectly generated by the `Export Data` module code with account information. May I think the code is old and not compatible with the new V2 storage API or API version information. You can report it to `feedback.azure.com`.

However, I switched to use `SAS` authentication type to type a blob url with a SAS query string of my container which I generated via [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/) tool as below, it works fine.

Fig 1: Right click on the container of your Blob Storage account, and click the `Get Shared Access Signature`

[image]

Fig 2: Enable the permission `Write` (recommended to use UTC timezone) and click `Create` button

[image]

Fig 3: Copy the `Query string` value, and build a blob url with a container SAS query string like `https://<account name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container name>/<blob name><query string>`

[image]

***Note: The blob must be not exist in the container, otherwise an [Error 0057](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/errors/error-0057) will be caused.***

Comment: Thanks that really helps.